# Java script not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I wanted to implement js function in my ASP.net webpage auto fill a text box when i am typing in a another text box.i am using telerik.
Here is the function that I used.

```
function Copy() {
    var val1 = document.getElementById('<%= txtAddress.ClientID %>').value;
    document.getElementById('<%= txtBillingAddress.ClientID %>').value = val1;
}
```

here is the asp.net code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <label>
            Address:
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Width="230px" BorderColor="#ABC1DE" BorderStyle="Solid"
            BorderWidth="1px" AutoPostBack="true" onkeyup="Copy();"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>
            Billing Address:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBillingAddress" runat="server" Width="230px" BorderColor="#ABC1DE"
            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" TabIndex="11"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

it dose not fire to js function.what I am missing here?

Comment: it works fine for me and where is telerik control

Comment: check your browser java script support is on or not. and do check your code if it causes some post back!

Comment: thank you very much your fast reply. that is the problem it works on other forms.but i face this problem to only in two forms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well i forgot tell i'm in the user control. btw i have found the solution fro my question.
if you are used ajax in your parent form java scripts will not working in your user control.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your table and javascript on my sample solution and It works on my end.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Copy() {
        var val1 = document.getElementById('<%= txtAddress.ClientID %>').value;
        document.getElementById('<%= txtBillingAddress.ClientID %>').value = val1;
    }
</script>
```

> ```
> <table>
>     <tr>
>     <td>
>         <label>
>             Address:
>         </label>
>     </td>
>     <td>
>         <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Width="230px" BorderColor="#ABC1DE" BorderStyle="Solid"
>             BorderWidth="1px" AutoPostBack="true" onkeyup="Copy();"></asp:TextBox>
>     </td>
>     <td>
>         <label>
>             Billing Address:</label>
>     </td>
>     <td>
>         <asp:TextBox ID="txtBillingAddress" runat="server" Width="230px" BorderColor="#ABC1DE"
>             BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" TabIndex="11"></asp:TextBox>
>     </td>
>     </tr>
> </table>
> ```

Comment: Why I got a negative feedback? I was trying to help... I don't have  enough reputation to do a comment. :(

Comment: thank you very much your fast reply. that is the problem it works on other forms.but i face this problem to only in two forms.

Comment: Kindly post the forms that you facing a problem.